# How to overwrite an existing image with c#?

Tags: c#

To save an image I use the following code:

```
 string filenamewithpath =
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
           @"~/userimages/" + incID + ".jpg");
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filenamewithpath, Util.ReadFully(image));


public class Util
    {
        public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above works for saving the image with an ID. When updating, I need to overwrite the existing image, and would need some advice on how to do this.

Comment: I dont see any EF or L2S code. Please add some code and chose exactly one of them.

Comment: why to save the image initially after successfull updation try to make changes and then save it.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to get rid of the old image file before writing the new one, why not just call

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filenamewithpath)
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(filenamewithpath);
}
```

Although, the description of System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes already says that "if the file exists, it is overwritten".

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filenamewithpath, Util.ReadFully(image));
```

replace this line with:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filenamewithpath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    var bytes=Util.ReadFully(image);
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```